Do psychedelics reduce brain activity which creates more complex subjective experiences?
There's a pop culture philosopher called Bernardo Kastrup who's been making the rounds arguing for metaphysical idealism.
He is ultimately arguing that modern understanding of neuroscience says that subjective experiences should be correlated with brain activity. So the more complex subjective experiences once has, the more brain activity.
He argues against this by saying psychedelics create rich subjective experiences while reducing brain activity, which he outlines in his paper.
It's not a long paper, but to summarise his points:

Brain activity under psychedelics is reduced. Some noted increase in cerebral blood flow in the visual cortex under LSD may ultimately be insignificant
Psychedelics are accompanied with rich inner experiences not seen in ordinary life
Normal convention works under the assumption that subjective life is accompanied with neural correlates of consciousness (NCCs). But if brain activity reduces while subjective experiences become richer, this defies usual intuitions. He argues there should at least be some local regions where brain activity does increase to support conventional intuitions

The author then tries to propose two approaches to solve this 'conundrum':

Brain scans may be too coarse to detect increases in brain activity in the NCCs related to the rich subjective experiences. This is because the parts of the brain not related to NCCs decrease enough to mask the increase of the NCCs. He thinks such a convenient pattern would be too unlikely

His second solution is to claim that the neural correlates for psychedelic experiences are always happening but as unconscious processes, and psychedelics somehow converts these into NCCs. His problem with this is twofold.

One, it would seem to be evolutionarily wasteful to be having these psychedelic trips in the background all the time
Two, we are able to detect NCCs for objects someone may be looking at in a dream, which have less experiential richness than visuals from a trip, so these unconscious psychedelic processes should be more detectable as they would have more brain activity



I thought his arguments might be too simplistic and the framing may be entirely wrong. For example he doesn't take into account how psychedelics connect up different parts of the brain that don't normally connect. Apparently neuroscientist Christoph Koch almost embraces his ideas, which gave me pause for thought since I don't know much about this. That being said, active researchers like Anil Seth do disagree with him, but with understandably not that much commentary, so I thought I would ask here to get more.
I'm interested to know what exactly may be missing or erroneous from these claims.
